# Connect android device to Virtual machine for debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, virtual-machine

I have installed android studio 2.2.2 on a windows 7 virtual machine. I want to use my phone for debugging but the problem is that android studio could not found it. Device was installed successfully on my VM, developer tools mode is on and the same device was used to debug from android studio installed on mac machine, and everything was working properly. So what could be the problem?

Comment: Please clarify: the phone is connected via USB to the machine that runs your Win 7 virtual machine? Which virtualization software are you using?

Comment: I am using VMware, Virtual machine is windows 7, local PC is windows 7, usb is connected to my local PC and I could successfully installed phone driver on VM and access all device files from VM

Comment: You may need to restart the adb server. Provided you have added tools and platform-tools directory inside Android SDK folder added to PATH, you can open cmd.exe or Terminal in Android Studio and enter: adb kill-server (new line) adb start-server. After that try adb devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to Search ADB driver for you device and install it on your Windows Virtual Machine

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I realized that other devices section in device manager of virtual machine is hidden while it is shown in portable devices. Any idea about how to solve this issue?

Comment: While installing adb driver on VM it could not catch my device because section other devices is not shown, so what is the problem?

Comment: Can you explain more, And you can search for the problem if it specific to you virtual machine